# Restricting access in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

To restrict access to pages one can check like below,

```
//This code is written on every page accessed by admin. Like, products.php, categories.php
if( !isset($_SESSION['admin_id'])) {
     header('Location: admin/login.php');
     exit();
}
```

What is the equivalent of the above code in Codeigniter, if i want to restrict access to every methods of the controller?

can i check for session in constructor like below?

```
//products.php

 class Products extends CI_Controller {
      public function __construct();

      if( !isset($_SESSION['admin_id'])) {
           redirect('admin/login.php');               
      }
}



//categories.php

 class Categories extends CI_Controller {
      public function __construct();

      if( !isset($_SESSION['admin_id'])) {
           redirect('admin/login.php');               
      }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a Simple way I usually use.

Create a controller in **`application/core`** as **`Admin_Controller.php`** and Extend it from the base controller, **`CI_Controller`** as,

```
/* application/core/Admin_Controller.php */

class Admin_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    protected $calledClass ;
    protected $calledMethod;
    protected $isAuthException;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->library("router");

        /* 
            add the controllers and the methods which don't need auth check.
            This is to assign any controller and it's methods to skip the auth
            check.

            Format : "{CONTROLLER}" => "{A METHOD}", "{Another METHOD}",
        */

        $authExceptions = array(

            "admin"     => array("login", "logout")

        );

        $this->calledClass = $this->router->fetch_class();
        $this->calledMethod = $this->router->fetch_method();

        $this->isAuthException = array_key_exists($this->calledClass,$authExceptions) && in_array($this->calledMethod, $authExceptions[$this->calledClass]);

        if(!$this->isAuthException && !isset($this->session->userdata('admin_id')))
        {
            redirect('admin/login.php');
        }
    }
}
```

Then, Extend your other admin related controllers from **`Admin_Controller.php`** as,

```
// application/controllers/products.php

 class Products extends Admin_Controller {
      public function __construct();

}

// application/controllers/categories.php

class Categories extends Admin_Controller {
      public function __construct();

}
```

Now, you don't need to check in every **`__contructor()`** method whether admin or not. Also some methods such as **login**, **logout** which don't need auth check will be skipped.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

In some cases, the simpler, the better

```
class Admin_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

        if(!$this->verify_admin_level()){
            redirect("home/block");

        }
    }

    private function verify_admin_level(){
        return $this->session->userdata("isAdmin");
    }


}
```

The home/block just shows the message: You must login as admin to access the required functionality